# PHPMailer AddAttachment

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am sending data from a form using PHPMailer, it's all connected correctly and works well for all my input fields. Except I am having problems sending a file upload as an attachment.

My php for the addattachment is below

```
if(is_array($_FILES)) {
  $mail->AddAttachment($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'],$_FILES['image']['name']); 
}
```

Here is the HTML for the input file to just so you can see it's basic

```
<input type="file" id="image" name="image" class="" />
```

The form submits but in the error_log it shows

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined index: image in /dir_location/mailer.php
```

Oh also just to rule out, I am using `<form id="form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

I have also tried

```
if (array_key_exists('image', $_FILES)) {
      $uploadfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), sha1($_FILES['image']['name']));

      if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
        $mail->addAttachment($uploadfile, 'UPLOAD file');
      }
}
```

But that didn't work either. Same issue.

Any advice from others would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Have you tried using [the file upload example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_file_upload.phps)?

Comment: Yes, it returns the exact same result.

Comment: You can't get an undefined index error if you're checking that the index exists first. What does `var_dump($_FILES);` show? Is that error message linked to a specific line, possibly of code you've not shown here?

Comment: var_dump just shows 

`array(0) {}`

Comment: So that explains the `$_FILES['image']` error. If you use the dev tools in your browser, does it show the correct content in the POST body? If so, you may have file uploads disabled in your PHP config. Read [the PHP docs on handling file uploads](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php).

Comment: Okay after some tests I think it's because I'm submitting my form with ajax. So using `$.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'mailer.php',
        data: formData
    })` seems to not keep the file I guess?

Comment: You should have mentioned that. Yes, ajax uploads do not normally include uploads - but search on that subject and you'll find workarounds, as it's definitely possible to make that work.

Comment: Yeah my fault, I'm now researching the topic. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With further research I found the solution if anyone is having problems with PHPMailer and Ajax submitting a file attachment.

Use the PHP docs provided with [PHPMailer for file upload](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_file_upload.phps), this worked with the final ajax amendments.

```
if (array_key_exists('userfile', $_FILES)) {

    $uploadfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), hash('sha256', $_FILES['userfile']['name']));

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
       // Attach the uploaded file
        $mail->addAttachment($uploadfile, $_FILES['userfile']['name']);
    //Send the message, check for errors
        if (!$mail->send()) {
            $msg = 'Sorry, something went wrong. Please try again later.';
        } else {
            $msg = 'Message sent! Thanks for contacting us.';
        }
    } else {
    }
}
```

Ajax for submitting the form, I needed to change the formData and add in the dataType.

```
$(function() {
  var form = $('#paymentForm');

    $(form).submit(function() {
      var formData = new FormData(this);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'mailer.php',
            data: formData,
            dataType : "json",
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false
        })
    });

});
```